# Akin to gauge field, why GR's lagrangian is not $R_{abcd}R^{abcd}$? What's the mathematical or physical meaning of $R_{abcd}R^{abcd}$?

Tags: general-relativity, mathematical-physics, differential-geometry, gauge-theory

For gauge field theory, the Lagrangian of the gauge field is $$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}\mathrm{tr}(\mathcal{F}_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{F}^{\mu\nu})=-\frac{1}{8}F_{a\ \mu\nu}F^{a \ \mu\nu}$$
The field  strength $F^a_{\phantom\a \mu\nu}$ where $\mu\nu$ is the coordinate index and
$a$  is the fiber index.

So analogous to the gauge field, $R_{abcd}$ where $ab$ is the fiber index and $cd$ is the
coordinate index. And akin to the Lagrangian of gauge field, the Lagrangian of gravity should 
be $R_{abcd}R^{abcd}$. While it is actually the Einstein-Hilbert action $R$. My questions are:

1. What's the mathematical or physical meaning of $R_{abcd}R^{abcd}$?
2. Why gravity's Lagrangian is not $R_{abcd}R^{abcd}$? If some field's Lagrangian is $R_{abcd}R^{abcd}$, what's the physical properties of this field?

Comment: There are 50 or so variations in the Wikipedia article [Alternatives to GR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternatives_to_general_relativity#Classification_of_theories), maybe you find more information why they are dismissed or set aside. The term pops up e.g. [Lovelock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lovelock_gravity) and [Gauss-Bonnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_gravity) gravity (which don't seem to live in 3+1 dimensions) and I guess in $f(R)$ variants.

Answer (score 1):

The Lagrangian for GR is

$$
L \propto \int R \sqrt{-g} \, d^4 x
$$

where $R$ is the Ricci scalar

$$
R = R^\mu_\mu = R^{\mu \nu}_{\mu \nu}
$$

So, this is a scalar which is related linearly to all the components of the Riemann tensor, and is a second-order differential of the metric $g$ of the form

$$
R \sim g \partial^2 g + (\partial g)^2
$$
This is typical for a Lagrangian. Your proposal involves the square of the Riemann tensor, and so is a non-linear second-order differential of $g$ with terms like $(\partial g)^4$ and $(\partial^2 g)^2$.

The concrete answer is that the Lagrangian shown above leads to Einstein's equations, and your suggestion doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

They are not analogous. $R_{abcd}$ is just Riemann Tensor and $R_{abcd}R^{abcd}$ is Riemann Tensor squared.

1. Mathematically they must be squared since having a Single term Riemann Tensor / Ricci Tensor in gravitational action doesn't make sense. Physically speaking they are modification of Einstein Hilbert action.
2. They are curvature not field one shall not confuse between the two. I encourage you to read Gauss-Bonnet gravity for a example of such theories.

Comment: But your dynamical variable isn't the riemann tensor, it is the metric tensor.  And $R$ contains a $g^{ab}\partial^{2}g_{ab}$ term, which can be integrated by parts to a $\partial^{c}g^{ab}\partial_{c}g_{ab}$ term.  This is the kinetic term that you want in an action.